# "Most notably the gene"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> New genetic technologies -- **perhaps** **most** **notably** **the** **gene** editing methods using a tool derived from a bacterial immune system called *CRISPR-Cas9* -- have reignited old debates and...

Could you please paraphrase the strong text, because it doesn't make sense to me.

It could have been made in this form "perhaps the most notable gene" So it could be understood

Comment: The noun phrase there is ***gene-editing methods*** - where the hyphen is orthographically optional, but it's important to note that ***gene-editing*** is an adjectival element modifying the primary noun ***methods***. Methods which are additionally defined/clarified as being those methods ***using / which use** a tool derived from a bacterial immune system called CRISPR -Cas9*.

Comment: The writer is saying that among various "new genetic technologies" which now exist, he's particularly interested in telling you about ***those*** methods. Compare with, say, *New companies, most notably Tesla, are investing heavily in electric cars.*

Comment: Thank you. Now it can make sense. Initially, I thought the sentence works this way: the gene [which is] editing methods. @FumbleFingers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rephrasing:

> ... perhaps, most notably, the **gene-editing methods** [which use] a tool ...

"Gene-editing methods" are, as you might expect, methods used to edit genes.  The author probably ought have included a hyphen to connect "gene" and "editing", but either way the meaning is the same.

In context:

> New technologies -- particularly this gene-editing method -- have reignited old debates.